# How to load different views in same content div tag without refreshing entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013, razor-2

I know must be possible to load different PartialViews in same div tag in my visual studio solution, I just can't get it. Here's a pic of what i want to make. I'm using razor to get the html, but can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

My html for the first option is like this

```
> <li><div id="abmPlan"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> ABM
> Plan</div></li>
```

My content wrraper is this

```
 <div id="page-wrapper"></div>
```

Suppose I have a test1 view in my menu controller just for testing.

I have already tried Doing it with actionLink but this creates a button and i don't want that cause I already have my markup good and running. Besides the menu dissapears and only shows my partial view in the body of the layout.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need an Ajax call. Either using jQuery or Ajax.ActionLink

Comment: Thanks dave. I had an example but didn't seemed to work $('#page-wrapper').load(@Url.Action('_ViandaPersonal', 'Menu')); inside on click method of my repective option. VS tells me about a "bad compile constant value." any suggestion for this?

Comment: Maybe `$('#page-wrapper').load(@{Url.Action("_ViandaPersonal", "Menu")})`

Comment: Didn't work. When I debbug this $('#abmPlan').on('click', function (e) {
        debugger;

        $('#page-wrapper').load( @{ Url.Action("VistaViandasPersonal", "Menu")} );

    }); 
The load appears to be without parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally did it. Here's the code.

```
 $('#abmPlan').on('click', function (e) {
        var base = window.location.origin + '/Plan/_ObtenerVistaPlan';
        $('#contenidoMenuAdministrador').load(base  );
    });
```

There was an issue with the URL, so I had to get the base URL and then set the corresponding path. Thanks to those who answered and tried to help me!